# How can I disable the rounding of buttons on a website through a Chromium browser?

Tags: javascript, css, button, styles, developer-console

I'm looking for a way to disable the rounding of all buttons on a website through the developer console. Thus far, nothing seems to work.
Can the button style be overridden across the entire script using Javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/52967/change-default-css-of-google-chrome

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to be something like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(( b ) => {
    b.style.borderRadius = "0";
    b.style.borderEndEndRadius = "0";
    b.style.borderEndStartRadius = "0";
    b.style.borderTopLeftRadius = "0";
    b.style.borderTopRightRadius = "0";
    b.style.borderBottomRightRadiusRadius = "0";
    b.style.borderBottomLeftRadiusRadius = "0";
    b.style.borderCollapse = "separate";
});

document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(( b ) => {
    b.style.borderRadius = "0";
    b.style.borderEndEndRadius = "0";
    b.style.borderEndStartRadius = "0";
    b.style.borderTopLeftRadius = "0";
    b.style.borderTopRightRadius = "0";
    b.style.borderBottomRightRadiusRadius = "0";
    b.style.borderBottomLeftRadiusRadius = "0";
    b.style.borderCollapse = "separate";
});
```

This code gets all buttons/a(s) in the html file then it loops foreach of them and it changes the borderRadius style to 0 "`none`", You can test `b.style.backgroundColor = "red";` and it will changes the selected item in the querySelectorAll() background's color to red.

More information about `document.querySelectorAll()` [here!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
Take a look on the `Array.prototype.forEach()` function in [here !](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: It looks like it will do exactly what I want it do to. Is it possible to implement this in my developer console when trying to temporarily change the style of a website?

Comment: Yes it is possible, Open the console by clicking (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+i) Then navigate to console tab then paste it and enter, Remember it's temporarily when you refresh the website it will come as it was before executing the code.

Comment: My apologies for the late reply. I tested it out but nothing changed in the document. Does this only apply to Firefox?

Comment: More specifically, when I attempted to run the command, the console showed that this function was "undefined".
https://i.imgur.com/HEOt85V.png

Did I run it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but i did example using vanillaJS for you , are you looking for something like this?

```js
function disableRounding(){
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (let button of buttons) {
    button.style.borderRadius = 0;
  };
};

function enableRounding(){
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (let button of buttons) {
    button.style.borderRadius = '50%';
   };
};
```

```css
.round-button {
    display:block;
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:#f5f5f5;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    background: #464646;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.round-button:hover {
    background: #262626;
}
```

```html
<button href="http://example.com" class="round-button" onclick="enableRounding()">Enable</button>
<button href="http://example.com" class="round-button" onclick="disableRounding()">Disable</button>
```

Comment: The code works perfectly when run in StackOverflow. My issue is the implementation. Is it possible to run this in a browser for a specific website?

Comment: Yes, open the console (F12) then paste it and enter.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tested it in my browser but nothing changed. Does this only apply to Firefox?

Comment: I think normally, this code should not be need browser separation.

Comment: Thanks for getting back!
The functions are defined as they should in the console, but I don't seem to be able to call them. Is there a specific procedure I need to use for them to work in my browser?